# How to build MuPDF on linux?

Tags: build, makefile, mupdf

Can anyone share their experiences building MuPDF on Ubuntu 12.04? If you can provide a step-by-step guide that would be awesome!

I would like to build mupdf-1.0-source but I'm having some trouble when invoking make.

One of my concerns is, where do you copy the contents inside thirdparty to?

I copied the contents into the source folder but have no luck with make =(

[@Jure] It gives:
`Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.`

However, I'd like to use the freetype library that is included in the `thirdparty` folder from mupdf. So my main concern is how do you tell make to include the thirdparty libraries?

Comment: what make troubles? can you show us errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about sharing experiences, I recently built Mupdf. Had some trouble with the directories and functions but they were all resolved.

1. Make sure you have downloaded Mupdf and its thirdparty libraries from their main website links:

   - http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=summary
   - http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/list
     I did the mistake of downloading the thirdparty libs from different sites.
2. As you have written you correctly extracted the thirdparty libs in the mupdf/thirdparty directory.
3. The pkg-config error says that it can't find the package in the `usr/lib/..` dir where the packages reside. This can be happening if you haven't extracted the thirdparty in the right place. or running `make` in the wrong directory.

Hope this helps!